# Quickly select arrays which have at least k elements common with master array

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, data-structures

I have `N` unique elements, indexed from 0 onwards, and a database of arrays created using these elements. The database is constant and doesn't change. A query array is given, different for each invocation.

I have to select the db arrays which have at least `K` elements (for instance, half) in common with the query array.

One solution I thought of: have a bit array of length `N`, set bits corresponding to query stack elements, and walk through the whole db once, filtering out arrays with < `K`. This is fairly scalable, but kinda slow, and a faster method seems possible...

Note:

- The query array can have elements **not** present in any db array.
- No array (db or query) has duplicate elements.
- Preprocessing can be done on the db arrays, to make certain operations faster, trading off memory for speed if required.

Comment: Is there any range for the values in the db arrays?

Comment: @thepace No, the elements are not necessarily numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use an **inverted index**.

It's what search engines do for finding matches to a query.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is fixed then you can build a table that contains item and array. So if you have two arrays:

```
A = {1, 7, 9, 12, 15}
B = {7, 12, 15}
```

Your table would be:

```
Item  Array
  1     A
  7     A
  7     B
  9     A
 12     A
 12     B
 15     A
 15     B
```

This is essentially an inverted index.

Now, given the query array `{1, 5, 7, 12}`, you can query the database for all of those items.

```
select * from ItemArrayIndex where Item in (1, 5, 7, 12) order by Array
```

And then count how many items exist for each array.

Come to think of it, you can probably get the count from a SQL query if you group by Array. My SQL is kind of rusty, though. . .